# How do I make my custom frame re-paint properly?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am trying to create my own custom GUI toolkit based on swing as a bit of a side project. My problem is this: I have created a frame with exit and minimize buttons however when I use the minimize button and maximise again, the window is not in the correct format. Here is my code for the frame class.

```
package com.SMS.GUI;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;


/**
 *
 * @author Marc
 */
final class SMSFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

GUIButton minimizeButton, exitButton;
JPanel titleBar;

SMSFrame(int width, int height){
    setResizable(false);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setSize(width,height);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#8e44ad"));
    setVisible(true);

    minimizeButton = new GUIButton((width-100),0,50,50,"#1abc9c");
    exitButton = new GUIButton((width-50), 0, 50, 50, "#d35400");
    titleBar = new JPanel();

    titleBar.setBackground(Color.decode("#2c3e50"));
    titleBar.setBounds(0, 0, width, 50);


    minimizeButton.addMouseListener(this);
    exitButton.addMouseListener(this);


    add(titleBar);
    titleBar.add(exitButton);
    titleBar.add(minimizeButton);

}


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == exitButton){
        exitButton.setBackground(Color.decode("#c0392b"));
    }

    if(e.getSource() == minimizeButton){
        minimizeButton.setBackground(Color.decode("#2ecc71"));
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == exitButton){
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if(e.getSource() == minimizeButton){
        super.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == exitButton){
        exitButton.setBackground(Color.decode("#e74c3c"));
    }

    if(e.getSource() == minimizeButton){
        minimizeButton.setBackground(Color.decode("#16a085"));
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == exitButton){
        exitButton.setBackground(Color.decode("#d35400"));
    }

    if(e.getSource() == minimizeButton){
        minimizeButton.setBackground(Color.decode("#1abc9c"));
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code for the custom buttons(I used JPanels).
    package com.SMS.GUI;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


final class GUIButton extends JPanel{
        GUIButton(int x, int y, int width, int height, String hexidecimal_colour){
        setBackground(Color.decode(hexidecimal_colour));
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }

        GUIButton(int width, int height, String hexidecimal_colour){
        setBackground(Color.decode(hexidecimal_colour));
        setSize(width, height);
    }
}
```

This is how the frame looks before minimizing:

[image]

This is how it looks after:
[image]

Comment: Off-topic tip: `"#1abc9c"` can be changed to `0x1abc9c`, which is an hexadecimal integer literal. You can then use it to construct a `Color` object with `new Color(0x1abc9c)`, without decoding a string ;)

Comment: @BackSlash good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> however when I use the minimize button and maximise again, the window is not in the correct format.

You really need to understand how Swing works if you want to customize a component. Swing was designed to be used with `layout managers`. The default layout manager for the content pane of a `JFrame` is a `BorderLayout`. The default layout manager for a `JPanel` is a `FlowLayout`.

The setSize() and/or setBounds() methods only work until the frame is "revalidated". When the frame is restored to is size the layout managers for each component are invoked and all the components are displayed at their preferred size.

```
titleBar = new JPanel();
```

So, the buttons on the "titleBar" get resized to their preferred size since they default `FlowLayout` is used. And the `FlowLayout` will then position the buttons in the center of the panel.

To fix this problem you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the `GuiButton` class. Also, get rid of all the location related code. It is up to the layout manager to set the location/size.

Since you want the buttons aligned to the right of the panel, you will need to change the layout manager to use a `right aligned FlowLayout`. Read the `FlowLayout` API for the proper constructor to use when creating the layout manager.

```
add(titleBar);
```

This adds the "titleBar" to the `CENTER` of the `BorderLayout`, so when the frame is revalidated, this panel will now cover the entire frame based on the rules of the `BorderLayout`.

To fix this you can use:

```
add(titleBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Now the titlebar will only appear at the top for the frame.

So you need to read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to understand these changes. The tutorial has working examples of both the `BorderLayout` and the `FlowLayout`.

I also suggest you read the section on [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for simple frame basics, including a better structure for you code. The example code shows the order of statement execution such that the `setVisible()` is the last statement.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful

Comment: @HeronimusLex, it is more than helpful, it is the proper solution. The answer you accepted does not address any of your design issues and is only a brute force solution to solving your problem.

Comment: You're right. Your answer has much more context and is, rather than being a quick solution to a single problem, will help with layouts in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to repaint or revalidate when you are Deiconifying you window. To do this, implements WindowListener and use this method :

```
@Override
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    //back to normal you could use this.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
    //do stuff here.
}
```

don't forget the  `this.addWindowListener(this);`

Also you extends JFrame so you could call  `this.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);` instead of `super` method. 
It's not a complete solution but it's definitly a problem of component painting.

Comment: No change I'm afraid. Thanks.